# Google scripts app- variable within variable error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Google drive script for searching- I can't add the variable for searchterm. As soon as I add it I continue to get errors - Perhaps I am going about it wrong?

Ultimately I would like a web app with a searchbox, button that searches for the terms. With the owneris variable...

```
function SearchFiles() {
//Please enter your search term in the place of Letter
var searchterm ='print';
var searchFor ='title contains "searchterm"';
var owneris ='and "youremail@yourdomain.com" in Owners';
var names =[];
var fileIds=[];
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor + owneris);
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  var fileId = file.getId();// To get FileId of the file
 fileIds.push(fileId);
 var name = file.getName();
 names.push(name);

}

for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
 Logger.log(names[i]);
Logger.log("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + fileIds[i]);

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add quotes in the right places and it should work:

```
var searchterm ="'print';
var searchFor ="title contains " + searchterm;
var owneris =" and 'youremail@yourdomain.com' in owners";
```

Be sure to change youremail@yourdomain.com

Comment: Great!it worked! Thanks for you help! Now I have to figure out how to get an input text box in google html to populate the searchterm variable. I may need to ask for more help!!